# Zend_Cache_Frontend_Page does not recognize output without echo

Tags: zend-framework

I am trying to fiddle around with Zend_Cache, so I added following code to my action (will be moved to bootstrap later, I guess):

```php
$frontendOptions = array(
    'lifetime' => 7200,
    'debug_header' => true, // für das Debuggen
    'default_options' => array(
        'cache' => true,
        'cache_with_get_variables' => true,
        'cache_with_session_variables' => true,
        'cache_with_cookie_variables' => true,
        'cache_with_post_variables' => true,
    )
);

$backendOptions = array(
    'cache_dir' => '/tmp/'
);

$cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Page', 'File',
    $frontendOptions, $backendOptions
);
echo "hej";
var_dump($cache->start('someid'));
```

Zend generates a cache file containing `hejbool(false)` now, but apart from that it does not cache my page. According to a German book about zend framework, **false** is correct when there is **no cache available**. true is only returned when a cache was found.

When I debugged within `Zend_Cache_Frontend_Page.php` directly, it went down to the bottom of the start()-method, meaning that nothing went wrong (id given) and no cache was found, so one had to be generated. This was done (I can see it in `/tmp/`), but without the needed content.

So why does not not cache the output from `Zend_View`, but only direct output via `echo`?

I do not call any explicit function to render the view, but this did not seem necessary anymore (my views are always rendered automatically according to controller and action). I tried it for both a standard XHTML template (`index.phtml`) and an RSS template (`index.rss.phtml`).

Any ideas? Do you need any other code fragments?

Comment: Have you added `Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->setParam('disableOutputBuffering', true)` in your Bootstrap or alternatively `resources.frontController.params.disableOutputBuffering = true` to your application's config file?

Comment: Thought this was easy ;) Add it as an answer, so I can mark this solved and give you some credits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `Zend_Cache_Frontend_Page` you have to enable the `disableOutputBuffering` option. The reason is that `Zend_Cache_Frontend_Page` uses [`ob_start`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) with a callback and it has to be the first call to `ob_start` otherwise it leads to that strange behaviour you've encountered.

To enable it you can either set it in your Bootstrap with

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->setParam('disableOutputBuffering', true);
```

or using the configuration file after your frontController-setup (here in the INI-style configuration):

```
resources.frontController.params.disableOutputBuffering = true
```